# Error when executing crashlyticsGenerateSymbols task with android gradle plugin 3.6+

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

Where do i report this error? or could anyone help me?

“Directory X specified for property ‘$2’ does not exist” error when executing crashlyticsGenerateSymbols task
with

```
android gradle plugin 3.6.0
gradle version 5.6.4
fabric gradle plugin 1.31.2
```

[Error logs]

```
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':~~~~~:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease' (type 'DefaultTask').

Directory '~~~' specified for property '$1' does not exist.
Directory '~~~~' specified for property '$2' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here. This error comes up when the Fabric Gradle plugin is trying to parse your project structure in order to find your stripped and unstripped binaries, and is unable to do so. When it asks for properties $1 and $2 it means it could not find the default paths to the ["obj" and "libs" folders](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#specifying-the-path-to-debug-and-release-binaries) that contain your supported ABIs folders with your supported native libraries there.

Using the legacy Fabric Gradle plugin, you can specify these paths under your crashlytics block in the build.gradle, like so:

```
crashlytics {
  enableNdk true
  androidNdkOut 'obj'
  androidNdkLibsOut 'libs'
}
```

In the case for builds that are on Android Studio 3.5 or later, you can usually find the paths for these somewhere in the outputted build folders under "merged_native_libs" and "stripped_native_libs."

If you're using the new Firebase Crashlytics SDKs and Gradle plugin, those paths are controlled by "strippedNativeLibsDir" and "unstrippedNativeLibsDir" flags in the firebaseCrashlytics block in your build.gradle.

If you continue running into problems feel free to [file a case with Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) with more details about your project and what you've tried to configure so far, and you can also still reach out to support@fabric.io.

Comment: I solved my issue and I appreciate your detail explanation.

Comment: I modified the path to the merged_native_libs and the stripped_native_libs folders and I solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on my side, and I fixed it by removing `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` from my app-level `build.gradle` in

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {
     // ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to gather NDK crash reports with Crashlytics, this won't help because you'll be disabling Crashlytics' initialization entirely.